# zurb foundation 4 carousel

Tags: carousel, zurb-foundation

I need a carousel component, that can show several images in a row and that will allow the user to flip through them - advancing one at a time.

Does anyone know of such a component?

ps
I know that if I put several images in one li of orbit (and float them) I get something similar. but that solution doesn't work well of different sizes of screens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that F4 supports that natively. Why not use something like this within a responsive Foundation div?

http://jcemer.com/zepto-carousel/

for example, modifying the example on github:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
      <div class="container">
          <ul>
              <li>Page 1</li>
              <li>Page 2</li>
              <li>Page 3</li>
              <li>Page 4</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I saw your answer too late and haven't had a chance to try it (so I can't accept it).

I ended up using flex slider (http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and customized it to make the swipe more natural.